# How to make a Mac Application that enlarge the Mouse Pointer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Change Mouse Pointer in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722607/how-to-change-mouse-pointer-in-mac)

what software I need to make a new application? with objective-c Language programming?

I want to make the mouse Pointer bigger so my kid can see that. The program will be residential like cinch. Then if I click the button I want a beep sound and a visual cue show up. That way I can train my 2 years old daughter to use the mouse.

How to do so?

I am familiar with objective-c but is currently building a program for IPhone. I want to make a program for iMac but the program should work like cinch (rather than windowed program)

NOTE:
This is not a duplicate. I am not asking how to enlarge mouse pointer. I am asking how to make a program to enlarge mouse pointer (so I can sell the program and practice objective-c, etc.). Also using the answer from the other answers sucks because the mouse button will show pixels. I want users to be able to customize their mouse pointers more comprehensively with a click of a button.

Comment: Duplicate (same user, migrated from SO yesterday): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722607/how-to-change-mouse-pointer-in-mac-migrated => http://superuser.com/questions/311458/how-to-change-mouse-pointer-in-mac

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am not asking how to enlarge mouse pointer. I am asking how to make a program to enlarge mouse pointer (so I can sell the program and practice objective-c, etc.). Also using the answer from that one sucks because the mouse button will show pixels.

Comment: How do you propose to sell a program that does something that Mac OS X already provides for free ?

Comment: Well I just want to make that. Forget about selling. What MAC do for free is inferior to what I have in mind and I wnat my daughter see youtube and click her self. It's important for her IQ that she knows computer at such early age

Comment: Well good luck with that - I suggest you start by reading Amit Singh's book, *Mac OS X Internals*: http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542

Answer (score 3):

No need to write any software. No need even to *install* any software.

`System Preferences` => `Universal Access` => `Mouse & Trackpad` => `Cursor Size`:

[image]